# Fitting with V matrices

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am trying to do a linear regression without using polyfit or polyval. This is part of a long project and I really want to complete it without using these functions. I think I have figured out the polyfit part but do not know how to compensate for polyval. here is what I have so far:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
y = [2.50922 2.12187 1.88092 1.94206 2.25718 2.79674 3.22682 4.09267 4.98531 6.37534]';
V = [x.^3 x.^2 x x.^0];
c = V \ y;   % same as c = (V' * V) \ (V' * y)

%To plot the points and the best fitting curve:

xs = (0:0.1:11)';
plot( x, y, 'o' )
hold on
plot( xs, polyval( c, xs ) );
```

Is this the correct way of compensating for polyfit? And how would I do this without using polyval?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the equation you solve to find the coefficients, `y=Vc`, now you know `V` and `c` so use that to find the corresponding `y`:

```
yFit=[xs.^3 xs.^2 xs xs.^0]*c;
```

Are you happy with the setup to find `c` using `V\y`, do you understand how/why it works?

EDIT: To fit higher-degree functions programmatically, you can do something like this. Hopefully it is obvious what is going on.

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
y = [2.50922 2.12187 1.88092 1.94206 2.25718 2.79674 3.22682 4.09267 4.98531 6.37534]';

V=[x.^0];
xs = (0:0.1:11)';
Vfit=[xs.^0];
for i=1:length(x)
    V = [x.^i V];
    c = V \ y;

    Vfit = [xs.^i Vfit];
    yFit=Vfit*c;

    plot(x,y,'o',xs,yFit,'--')

    drawnow
    pause
end
```

In the first loop, this fits a straight line to the data, second time it fits a quadratic, then a cubic, and so on.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I do understand how it works. I did some research on linear regression and believe it to deal with Vandermonde matrices. I do however have another question for you. Below I posted my code at the minute and was wondering if you could give me some insight on how I may apply this to it.

Comment: Cool, and the other thing is that the \ operator in Matlab will do a least-squares solution to the matrix equation if it is overdetermined, which it should be for curve-fitting.

Comment: For some reason it wont let me type but do you know how I would implement this method if I wanted to put it in a loop. For example if I wanted the fit to continue adding orders until a certain residual is reached. I completed this with polyfit and polyval but am not sure how to do it without them. Ive sent you the code.

Comment: I am not sure how to control the order of the polynomial with this method.

Comment: If my last little edit doesn't help, it's probably best to start a new question.

Comment: I didnt see the pause the first time. I understand it now. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel for some reason this does not work with with my function because it is not fitting it well. I have posted another question with my function. I kept the code exactly the same as above just added my function.